# How to short Turkey? How to get exposure to local currency-denominated debt?

Tags: bonds, shorting-securities, turkey

After some research, I decided to open a short position on Turkish Lira (TRY), and I'm also looking to short TRY-denominated debt.

To short the TRY-denominated debt, I'd need to short-sell a TRY-denominated bond.

The entry threshold to buy/sell government or corporate bonds is around $200K, what is above what I am willing to risk.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Does your broker have access to securities listed on the Borsa Istanbul?

Comment: I use Interactive Brokers, it seems they don't have it. Is it a good idea to register with one of their local brokers, open short positions on their local debt (and go long TRY), and then open a mirroring short position for USDTRY?

Comment: Full-fledged brokers should be able to arrange transactions on most stock exchanges around the world. Why not give your broker a call? You could also try to contact the stock brokerage divisions of major banks to ask if they will help you with your order. I have no particular comment on the specific transaction(s) you want to do.

Comment: some research? You want to speculate in currencies after "some" research? Even seasoned investors try to avoid currency. You'll be a koi fish in a shark pond.

Answer (score 3):

Short, but not an indefinite, answer to your question for short-selling TRY bonds is I don't think it is possible, for retail investors, even in Turkey, perhaps unless one has very significant funds.

As a Turkish person who does occasionally trade various Turkish financial assets, I have never heard local banks or brokers lending local bonds for short selling to retail investors. A retail investor can make a reverse repurchase agreement (reverse repo) backed by local bonds with a local bank but s/he can not actually get hold of the bonds and sell them somewhere else.

A local retailer can short local shares or, of course, local currency, by borrowing either and then selling it through either [Borsa Istanbul](https://www.borsaistanbul.com/en/) or over-the-counter (OTC) markets as appropriate.

Borsa Istanbul has a [bond market](https://www.borsaistanbul.com/en/sayfa/2950/debt-securities-market) mainly for government or privately issued TRY bonds but one can not officially sell bonds short in that market.

There is also a [futures market](https://www.borsaistanbul.com/en/sayfa/2964/derivatives-market-viop) in Borsa Istanbul but it is mainly for certain local equity indices, certain local stocks (single stock futures), local currency vs USD or EUR, and certain precious metals. Options on certain stocks, equity indices, and currencies are also available through Borsa Istanbul but they are illiquid and expensive.

From what I know, some of the institutional investors insure their  Turkish bond holdings, or bet against them, using Turkish credit default swaps (CDS). However, Turkish CDS's are only available for Turkish government-issued eurobonds which are issued either only in USD or EUR. In addition, CDS's can not be bought in small quantities and they are only available through OTC markets.

---

**Update**

Should you ever need one, Turkish Capital Markets Association has a book in English called [Handbook of the Turkish Capital Markets](https://www.tspb.org.tr/en/reference-documents/?lang=en), available free of charge in pdf.

Answer (score 0):

One major U.S. broker's international trading doesn't offer Turkey.

Then to open an account in a foreign country, without being a resident, usually requires forming a company in that country and having a registered agent in that country. Some websites recommend Northern Cyprus for access to the Turkish financial system.

Or in a home country account, consider buying the USD/TRY currency pair while selling the USD/RUB currency pair.

Comment: Thank you. I will reach out to local brokers to see if they can open an account for me

Comment: Why do you recommend selling USDRUB?

Comment: In a dollar forex account, a sell of the USD/RUB could be a hedge of a buy of the USD/TRY. Basically, the idea is that if TRY is targeted as a short then TRY should do worse against the dollar than the RUB. Also, a buy of the USD/TRY will have a rollover interest cost while a sell of the USD/RUB will receive a rollover interest but not receive as much as the USD/TRY costs.

Comment: If the margin requirement on the sell of the USD/RUB is too high, then the buy of the USD/TRY might be hedged with a buy of the EUR/USD.

Comment: So basically a long USDTRY and short USDRUB position means just long RUBTRY position, correct? I am not sure what will happen with Russia in this environment (shortage of dollars; manufacturing exports disruption; increasing wealth gap, rising risks of a conflict). I am not certain RUB won't go down with TRY altogether, therefore I shouldn't go long RUBTRY. Do you agree with me?

Comment: When you say "then the buy of the USD/TRY might be hedged", do you mean "hedging against the risk of having the dollar devaluate as well as the TRY, and not getting the full profit out of the trade"?

Comment: Well, Russia is said to have three to five years of foreign currency reserves to sell while waiting for oil to rebound. So Russia is expected to buy the rubble. The purpose of a sell of the USD/RUB is just to reduce the volatility of a buy of the USD/TRY and to reduce the payment of rollover interest. The purpose of a buy of the EUR/USD is just a hedge of cross-Atlantic trade in general. Now being long RUB/TRY also relates to the base currency of the account and so I related to a dollar account.